# firewalld config without interface declaration

Tags: configuration, firewalld

In my custom firewalld zone file, I defined various ports, and this:

```xml
<interface name="eth0"/>
```

The firewall works as expected, whether I include that or not.

Is it strictly necessary? Are there unintended consequences to removing it?